# SVG oncontextmenu not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

I am generating svg on my html page using JavaScript. 
In a loop, i am adding oncontextmenu atributte like so:

```
      mapString += "<rect x='" + (y * tileSize) +
    "' y='" + (i * tileSize) +
    "' width='" + tileSize + "' height='" + tileSize +
    "' fill='" + fill +
    "' stroke='black' oncontextmenu='flagTile(" + i +
    "," + y + "," + mapName +")' onclick='" +
    "openTile(" + i + "," + y + "," + mapName + ")'></rect>";
```

The code works as intended in chrome, internet explorer, and edge, 
but oncontextmenu won't trigger in firefox. Any suggestions to what the problem is  and how to reasonably fix it? As you can see, i would prefer to be able to add it inline, since it would be very inconvinient to add at any later point.

Comment: In Firefox, you can disable the `contextmenu` event entirely using `about:config` (`dom.event.contextmenu.enabled`). Not sure if that is your problem, though.

Comment: use addEventListener instead

Comment: @Robert Longson, i could, but as said, that would be very unconvinient, since I would have to add it at a much later point in the code, and it would be less efficient also. + It wouldn't work in IE 8 and lower

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Your options are currently a) useEventListener b) write a patch in C++ to implement oncontextmenu in Firefox c) give up on Firefox compatibility.